# Mongoose JS path default generating id

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Take a look at the following schema:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  fullName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    index: true
  },
  activationId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId
  }
});

userSchema.path('activationId').default(function() {
  return new mongoose.Schema.ObjectId.fromString('actvt');
});
```

It is about the "activationId", I want to generate an ID (unique code, objectID prefered since that is already built-in Mongoose) once a user gets created, so if I have the following code:

```
var newUser = new User({
  fullName: 'Rick Richards'
});

newUser.save(function(error, data){
  console.log(data.activationId); // Should give the activationId
});
```

But this solution gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by defining a `default` property for the `activationId` field that's the `ObjectId` constructor function:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  fullName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    index: true
  },
  activationId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId
    default: mongoose.Types.ObjectId
  }
});
```